# save short-code in my custom plugin settings problem missed something

Tags: plugins, customization, shortcode, options

i want to have dynamic shortcode to CF7

when i create new Contact form the id is different from develop env to production

i decide to put my shortcodes in my plugin settings.

and use them as option

```
            <?php
            echo do_shortcode(get_option("email_ShortCode_text"));
            ?>
```

the more important code is this code that used in setting:

```
        <p>Enter your email_shortcode
        </p> <input type="text" name="email_ShortCode_text" value="<?php echo get_option('email_ShortCode_text'); ?>" />

        <hr />
```

but when user put his shortcode in my plugin setting then save it worked

but second time when shortcodes raed from database missed some characters

so when save all those settings missed

please help me

how can i convert setting to normal string when read from wordpress?

thank you

Comment: The more important code here is the code for adding and saving the setting.

Comment: thank you ... i put it here for you.

Answer (score 0):

just need to use text area instead of input in your settings page:

```
        <p>Enter your email shortcode
        </p> <textarea type="text" name="email_ShortCode_text" > <?php echo stripslashes(get_option('email_ShortCode_text')); ?>" </textarea>

        <hr />
```